# Trying to open / access the text in an attachment to an email using ruby gems

Tags: ruby, email, rubygems, mail-gem

currently trying to write a code to extract text from a text file attachment in an email using ruby gems. Using the 'mail' gem.

this is what the code I found to isolate the body looks like:

```
mail = Mail.all
mail.each do |current_mail|
mail_object = Mail.read_from_string(current_mail)
puts mail_object.body
end
```

and this works good to find the body but when we attach a .txt file it returns this:

```
--_000_DM6PR04MB6138740F20BC287E0587E27281720DM6PR04MB6138namp_--

--_004_DM6PR04MB6138740F20BC287E0587E27281720DM6PR04MB6138namp_
Content-Type: text/plain;
name=readable.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
creation-date="Mon, 27 Jul 2020 21:10:20 GMT";
filename=readable.txt;
 modification-date="Mon, 27 Jul 2020 21:10:22 GMT";
 size=16
Content-Description: readable.txt
Y2FuIHdlIHNlZSB0aGlzPw==
--_004_DM6PR04MB6138740F20BC287E0587E27281720DM6PR04MB6138namp_--
```

So I can see it has **located the attachment** name and **file name** but is there a way from here to access the text in this file?

Comment: Did you have a look at [the documentation](https://github.com/mikel/mail/#testing-and-extracting-attachments)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text file attachment will be Base64 encoded. So you should be able to just decode it like this.

```
puts current_mail.attachments.each{|a| a.decode_body}
=>"can we see this?"
```

Comment: Yeah just needed a base 64 decode which I realized yesterday. I used :         text = Base64.decode64 attachment.body.parts[1].body.raw_source